# Join Array of Objects by Property javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have `array of objects`:

> `var x = [{a: 1,b:2}, {a:3,b:4}, {a: 5,b:6}];`

I need to join array as follows:

```
1,2 
3,4
5,6
```

I do not want to use from `lodash` or `underscore`

How can I get Join of `array of objects` ?

Comment: `Array` of `arrays` ?

Comment: How Join Array Of objects

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
const x = [{a: 1,b:2}, {a:3,b:4}, {a: 5,b:6}];    
console.log(x.map(Object.values));
```

Output:

```
[
  [1,2],
  [3,4],
  [5,6]
]
```

Furthermore, if you really want a string (not clear from your question)

```
x
  .map(o => Object.values(o).join(','))
  .join('\n')
```

Comment: nice use of `Object.values`

Comment: [___`Object.values` is not a `function`___](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: @Rayon, interesting, I didn't know it had such lousy support. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @mash – `Chrome 51.0`... That is too latest.. Without [`Polyfill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values#Polyfill) it should not be used...

Comment: Btw, it can even be `x.map(Object.values)`

Comment: @mash – For me, it is still a fresh fish.. And what about `Internet Explorer Opera Safari` ? __No support__

Comment: @Rayon not available in w3m and links either.

Comment: And probably that is why @mash did not make `executable-snippet` :P

Comment: @Rayon well [IE Edge 14, FF47, Chrome 51 Flag](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/) not too great but let's be honest who would really deploy es6+ without something like [Babel](https://babeljs.io) these days?

Answer (score 4):

A simple map will do it !

```js
let xs = [{a: 1,b:2}, {a:3,b:4}, {a: 5,b:6}]
let out = xs.map(({a,b})=> [a,b])
console.log(out)
//=> [ [1,2], [3,4], [5,6] ]
```

Here's a pre-ES6 answer to help

```js
var xs = [{a: 1,b:2}, {a:3,b:4}, {a: 5,b:6}]
var out = xs.map(function(x) { return [x.a, x.b] })
console.log(out)
//=> [ [1,2], [3,4], [5,6] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

i use this code :

`x.map(Object.values).join("\n")`